# Visual Studio 2012 Web Test Editor Not Opening

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a .webtest file in a test project. When I right click / `Open With` and select `Web Test Editor`, the file opens in that editor. In the `Open With` dialog, `Web Test Editor` is set as `(Default)`.

When I double-click the same file, it opens as XML. I want the default editor to open when I double click!

I've tried `Open With`, setting the default to something else, and then setting it back to `Web Test Editor` to no avail.

Is there any way to reset all of the editor defaults?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When browsing history in version control, I noticed that `<SubType>Designer</SubType>` had been added to the item in the .csproj XML. Deleting that line fixed the glitch.

Comment: This saved me a few hours

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to elaborate that the `<SubType>Designer</SubType>` node(s) are located in the csproj file.

To access this:

1. Find the path of the Project (or solution) in Visual Studio.
2. Navigate that location using Windows Explorer.
   --> You should see the Project name file ending with .csproj format.
3. Right click and 'edit' the file with Notepad or NotePad++
   --> Voila.  Delete the `<SubType>Designer</SubType>` sections as necessary.